# 'mesaageadded' twilio chat channel event excuting multiple times..why?

Tags: node.js, twilio, event-listener, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

getting in this problem from 3 days ..
 I use twilio programmable chat to integrate chat system ,
so when a massage added in channel used this event according to doc
https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/tutorials/chat-application-node-express

now this my code //   in first line i initalize the twilio client in 2nd line i get channel in 3Rd line i send message to channel whenever new message occur this mesaageAdded event excute but it excuting multiple times

```js
async sendmsg(){
      try{
        let client = await Twilio.Chat.Client.create(this.token);
        var myChannel = await client.getChannelByUniqueName(this.thisChat.channel.uniqueName); 
        var newMessage =  await myChannel.sendMessage(this.msg); 
        myChannel.on('messageAdded', function(message) {  
          console.log(message.author+ 'in chrome', message.body);
        });
      } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
```

when excuting of massageadded event, it is with click multiple times

this is my html code in nuxt js

```js
<div class="paddingLR10 text-center"><i @click="sendmsg" class="material-icons fontLarge">send</i></div>
```

These are the outpus in console

```js
7_id.vue?21cd:72 Ashu Rastogiin chrome ggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
5_id.vue?21cd:72 Ash_Rasgiin chrome ggggg2
6_id.vue?21cd:72 Ash_Rasgiin chrome ggggg233333333333
```

this 7,5,6 is times of the excuting callback on click on the send msg
please correct me i'm stucking in this error from last 3 days and now idea what's going on

if u need more details please let me know...

Comment: please let  me know if someone know the answer..if needs  more information please let me know...why this on('messaeAdded',callback) excuting muliptle times

Comment: Try this: reload the page. Click the button one single time. What is logged to the console? (I'm asking this question for a specific reason, your answer will help me help with your issue)

Comment: Make sure you are only adding one event listener.

Comment: when i reload the page  it wiil start again means on 1st click 0, 2nd click 1 time......on 5th click 4 times it excuted .....the partinside callback excuted multiple times @KayakinKoder

Comment: how will i make sure it is adding only one time ...did not get it ...please correct me @LancePollard

Comment: So on the first click everything works correctly. On the second click everything works correctly. Right? I would next recommend moving `client` and `myChannel` outside of `sendmsg`. I'm not familiar with this specific twilio api you're using but it seems like those two things should only be created one single time. That may fix your problem

Comment: not everything is working fine after registering those event handler when page is loaded. like moutned function

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?